# Install RPostgreSQL to connect to Postgres.app

Tags: r, macos, postgresql

I am trying to install `RPostgreSQL` on a Mac running OSX 10.9.5 (Mavericks) and R 13.4.0 (Darwin). I guess I don't have a running Postgres installation on my system since, from Terminal:

```
% which postgres
postgres not found
```

I use `[Postgres.app][1]`

I tried installing `RPostgreSQL` from [source](https://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/source/checkout)

```
library(devtools)
install('~/Downloads/rpostgresql-read-only/RPostgreSQL')
```

but I get the error

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-Kthread'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-kthread'
make[1]: *** [fe-auth.o] Error 1
make: *** [libpq/libpq.5.dylib] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RPostgreSQL’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/RPostgreSQL’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

which is not exactly self-explanatory. I google it but I couldn't find any relations with `RPostgreSQL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do a hack install by removing the 2 -KThread flags from the MakeFile.global.darwin.  I can't tell you what the -KThread flag was and why its needed, but it seemed to install fine for Mavericks (10.9.5)

PTHREAD_CFLAGS      =   -Kthread -kthread -pthread -pthreads  -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS

changed to

PTHREAD_CFLAGS      =   -pthread -pthreads  -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS

Comment: It worked. I was able to install the package. But I also got `clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthreads'` at different points during compilation. Did you get the same warning?

Comment: I did get that same warning.

Comment: After fighting this for so long, I found something that helped me much more.  The reality is that I'm trying to connect to to Redshift, not just Postgres.  This link might help you as well.  https://github.com/pingles/redshift-r

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibly more user-friendly approach described at [this blog](http://computersandbuildings.com/how-to-install-rpostgresql-on-osx-mavericks/) with additional notes at the bottom of the PecanProject [GitHub repo issue thread](https://github.com/PecanProject/pecan/issues/131).

You'll probably have to manually link to the directory with `pg_config` file to address the `'libpq-fe.h' file not found` issue. In my case, the command was different from that mentioned in the PecanProject issue thread:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/bin/pg_config /usr/local/bin/
```

I then had to

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql /usr/local/opt/postgresql
```

to get around a `Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib` error.

A final hat-tip to [Chris Chou](http://blog.chrischou.org/2010/09/07/install-rpostgresql-in-mac/) for that last point.